# Is Doc2Vec suited for Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have been reading more modern posts about sentiment classification (analysis) such as [this](http://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/modern-methods-for-sentiment-analysis).

Taking the IMDB dataset as an example I find that I get a similar accuracy percentage using Doc2Vec (88%), **however a far better result using a simple tfidf vectoriser with tri-grams for feature extraction (91%)**. I think this is similar to Table 2 in [Mikolov's 2015 paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5335v7.pdf).

I thought that by using a bigger data-set this would change. So I re-ran my experiment using a breakdown of 1mill training and 1 mill test from [here](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/). Unfortunately, in that case my tfidf vectoriser feature extraction method increased to 93% but doc2vec fell to 85%.

**I was wondering if this is to be expected and that others find tfidf to be superior to doc2vec even for a large corpus?**

My data-cleaning is simple:

```
def clean_review(review):
    temp = BeautifulSoup(review, "lxml").get_text()
    punctuation = """.,?!:;(){}[]"""
    for char in punctuation
        temp = temp.replace(char, ' ' + char + ' ')
    words = " ".join(temp.lower().split()) + "\n"
    return words
```

And I have tried using 400 and 1200 features for the Doc2Vec model:

```
model = Doc2Vec(min_count=2, window=10, size=model_feat_size, sample=1e-4, negative=5, workers=cores)
```

Whereas my tfidf vectoriser has 40,000 max features:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 40000, ngram_range = (1, 3), sublinear_tf = True)
```

For classification I experimented with a few linear methods, however found simple logistic regression to do OK...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code Mikolov once posted (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/word2vec-toolkit/Q49FIrNOQRo/J6KG8mUj45sJ) used options `-cbow 0 -size 100 -window 10 -negative 5 -hs 0 -sample 1e-4 -threads 40 -binary 0 -iter 20 -min-count 1 -sentence-vectors 1` – which in gensim would be similar to `dm=0, dbow_words=1, size=100, window=10, hs=0, negative=5, sample=1e-4, iter=20, min_count=1, workers=cores`.

My hunch is that optimal values might involve a smaller `window` and higher `min_count`, and maybe a `size` somewhere between 100 and 400, but it's been a while since I've run those experiments.

It can also sometimes help a little to re-infer vectors on the final model, using a larger-than-the-default `passes` parameter, rather than re-using the bulk-trained vectors. Still, these may just converge on similar performance to Tfidf – they're all dependent on the same word-features, and not very much data.

Going to a semi-supervised approach, where some of the document-tags represent sentiments where known, sometimes also helps.

Comment: That's very helpful - I will try! However, do you think the concept of using context to infer similar words will naturally mix synonyms and antonyms. For example: "This is movie is good", "This movie is bad" -> good and bad will have a high cosine. This means in the final vector space the good and bad sentiments will be very close together and harder to separate/classify?

Comment: It is true that distributional models often consider antonyms to be similar. And often, such words are quite similar – except in the one foreground aspect in which they differ. Whether this presents a problem for sentiment-classification, or there's still enough contrast, would need to be resolved experimentally. The act of training is still inducing different vectors for word-vecs/doc-vecs that need to predict nearby 'good' or 'bad'.